# App return me to Home Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently trying to make a login with Facebook for my website.

Currently I have just made a simple app, which should echo out the users first name, but it just redirects me to `http://facebook.com/`

EDIT: I here is my PHP source, of my example:

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '****************',
'secret' => '****************',
'cookie' => true, ));
$req_perms = "publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,email,read_stream";

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=>1,'fbconnect' => 0,'req_perms'=>$req_perms));
$me = null;

if (!$session) { echo "<script>top.location.href= '$loginUrl';</script>";exit;}

else{

 try {
        $uid    =   $facebook->getUser();
        $me     =   $facebook->api('/me');
     } 
 catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
   { echo $me['firstname']; exit;}
}

 ?>
```

EDIT: I have made a remake, to upgrade the getSession() to the getUser().

But it is still just redirecting to Facebook's home page. Any ideas?

New source:

```
<?php

require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = '116624645175305';
$config[‘secret’] = 'a6b557e6d703328d0cac9db47b20ae98';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional
$config[‘cookie’] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$req_perms = "publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,email,read_stream";

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=> 1,'fbconnect' => 0,'req_perms' => $req_perms));
$user_info = null;
if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";exit;
}else{
    try {
        $user_info = $facebook->api('/me');
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>"; exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook SDK for PHP has no method getSession();

Comment: Thanks. I have made a remake of my code to use the `getUser();` instead of the `getSessions();`, but it does still redirects me to Facebook's Home page, any other ideas?